# Setting Opacity in CSS For Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, opacity

I've tried the following:

(this is actually for fancybox, as the overlay does not show in chrome/safari:

```
   $("#fancy_overlay").css({<br />
                    'background-color': opts.overlayColor,<br />
                    'opacity': opts.overlayOpacity,<br />
                    '-moz-opacity': opts.overlayOpacity,<br />
                    '-khtml-opacity': opts.overlayOpacity,<br />
                    '-webkit-opacity:' : opts.overlayOpacity<br />
    }).show();
```

And still nothing (in chrome/safari)

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`opacity` should work for chrome/safari/firefox. The -moz and -khtml syntaxes are only used to support the much older versions of these browsers.

I've never run across the `-webkit-opacity` style before and can't seem to find any documentation that says it exists. I would try removing it entirely or fixing the syntax bug you have in there: `'-webkit-opacity:'` to `'-webkit-opacity'` (without the trailing colon).

If that doesn't work try printing the value of `opts.overlayOpacity`. Make sure it's something like `0.5` and not `50` or `50%`.

Comment: Sure I tought 50% to be equivalent to 0.5, but your comment saved me some time. ;)