# CSS opacity working in Firefox & Internet Explorer, but not Chrome & Safari (WebKit)

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, webkit

I have a strange issue on an asp.NET page I am developing. I set the opacity of a .NET hyperlink control using the "CssClass" property at design-time. The opacity takes effect in Firefox & IE, but not Chrome & Safari.

Browser versions I am using:

Chrome: 49
Internet Explorer: 11
Firefox: 44.0.2
Safari: 5.1.7

**Working snippet:**

```css
body {
    color: white;
}

.menuContent {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.menuTable {
    table-layout: fixed;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    border-spacing: 40px;
}

.expensesCell {
    height: 300px;
    width: 300px;
    text-align: center;
    border: 5px solid white;
    background-clip: padding-box;
    border-radius: 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 2.5em;
    vertical-align: middle;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.menuLink {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin: -10em;
    padding: 10em;
}

.expensesCell:hover {
    background-color: lightsteelblue;
    border-color: yellow;
    color: yellow;
}

.expensesCell {
    background-color: rgb(22,167,67);
}

.disabledMenuItem {
    opacity: 0.1;
    cursor: default;        
}
```

```html
<div class="menuContent">
    <table class="menuTable">
        <tr>
            <td class="expensesCell">
                <a id="HyperLinkExpenses" href="staff/Expenses.aspx" class="disabledMenuItem menuLink">
                    <div>Expenses</div>
                </a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Link where opacity has not taken effect (Safari):

[image: Safari]

And where it has the desired result (Firefox):

[image: Firefox]

I did a lot of research on how the browsers handle CSS, but from what I've seen the opacity should work on all of the browser versions I am testing on. I came across this [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1757425/setting-opacity-in-css-for-chrome) in regards to the opacity value in Chrome but again, the version I am using should not have this problem.

Can anyone tell me what the issue is here?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5640815/opacity-css-that-works-for-all-browsers

Comment: @Alexander O'Mara - edited question to follow Minimal, Complete & Verifiable example suggestions

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a long-standing bug in WebKit browsers like Safari, and WebKit-derived Blink browsers like Chrome and Opera. Basically, opacity does not normally work on inline display states like `display: inline` elements (which is the default for `a` tags).

The most-common way to work around this is to change the display state to something like, `display: block` or `display: inline-block`.

## Working example:

Adds `display: inline-block` to `.menuLink`.

```css
body {
    color: white;
}

.menuContent {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.menuTable {
    table-layout: fixed;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    border-spacing: 40px;
}

.expensesCell {
    height: 300px;
    width: 300px;
    text-align: center;
    border: 5px solid white;
    background-clip: padding-box;
    border-radius: 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 2.5em;
    vertical-align: middle;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.menuLink {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin: -10em;
    padding: 10em;
    display: inline-block;
}

.expensesCell:hover {
    background-color: lightsteelblue;
    border-color: yellow;
    color: yellow;
}

.expensesCell {
    background-color: rgb(22,167,67);
}

.disabledMenuItem {
    opacity: 0.1;
    cursor: default;        
}
```

```html
<div class="menuContent">
    <table class="menuTable">
        <tr>
            <td class="expensesCell">
                <a id="HyperLinkExpenses" href="staff/Expenses.aspx" class="disabledMenuItem menuLink">
                    <div>Expenses</div>
                </a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Alternately, another way to make it `opacity` work on the element would be to add positioning other than `relative` and `static`, like `position: absolute` or `position: fixed`, but this has other side-effects which are probably not ideal for your sample.